# How to hide a sidebar on GitHubs wiki page for certain pages?

Tags: github, markdown, wiki

It is easy to define a sidebar on GitHub's wiki page by creating `_Sidebar.md` file in the root and the sidebar will be automatically appended to every page. But what if we would like to hide it on certain pages, is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried putting an empty `_Sidebar.md` file in the directory in which you don't want a sidebar?

Answer (score 0):

This feature seems to [not be available for GitHub wikis](https://twitter.com/GitHubHelp/status/627210628403470336).

I have also tried the empty `_Sidebar.md` file as suggested by lucifurious, but all it does is create an empty (blank) sidebar below the "Pages" one.